# Eclipse Luna Runtime Workbench Error

Tags: eclipse

When starting Eclipse Luna Runtime workbench, I am getting the following error.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx [338]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: eclipse.platform; filter:="(osgi.os=macosx)"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Comment: Are you running on Mac OS X - because that is what the code is expecting to run on.

Comment: This error comes in Windows actually. I am not sure whether this is a bug or I need to put some settings.

Comment: What exactly are you running? Whatever it is it includes code that is Mac OS X specific.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue; I have org.eclipse.swt supposedly loading but then it has the following issues: (MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86, Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: eclipse.platform; filter:="(& (osgi.ws=gtk) (osgi.os=linux) (osgi.arch=x86))") with all the platforms that aren't my actual platform (linux x86_64). This is with the eclipse libraries from Luna as well. I'm pretty sure I'm missing an autostart somewhere but I have no idea.

Comment: I got a solution to get rid of these kind of errors. In runtime configuration > Plugins tab > Unselect the unwanted bundles.